Can't install kernel 6.8.0-44-generic upon upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04
I have ran into a problem, during dist upgrade ui tool stuck on grub update.
I have ran sudo apt --fix-broken install and it fixed quite a lot of things but now the system is stuck on installing kernel 6.8.0-44-generic.
It's quite an old laptop uses ralink bt and wifi adapter and dpkg can't find package for rt3290sta.
Hope someone can point me in the right direction what to do here.
While running sudo apt --fix-broken install i get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libilmbase25 libmpdec3 libopencolorio1v5 libopenexr25 libpython3.10 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libraw20 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 libyaml-cpp0.7
  linux-headers-6.8.0-44 linux-headers-6.8.0-44-generic linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic linux-modules-6.8.0-44-generic linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-44-generic
  linux-tools-6.8.0-44 linux-tools-6.8.0-44-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
applying patch rt3290sta.patch...patching file src/include/os/rt_linux.h
patching file src/Makefile
patching file src/os/linux/config.mk
patching file src/os/linux/Makefile.6
patching file src/os/linux/Makefile.clean
patching file src/os/linux/pci_main_dev.c
patching file src/os/linux/rt_linux.c
patching file src/tools/Makefile




Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-45-generic -C src/ LINUX_SRC=/lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rt3290sta: 2.6.0.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-45-generic/x86_64 failed for rt3290sta(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic; however:
  Package linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic (6.8.0-44.44
) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.8.0-44-generic
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-headers-generic (= 6.8.0-45.45); however:
  Package linux-headers-generic is not configured yet.


dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic
 (6.8.0-45.45) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
applying patch rt3290sta.patch...patching file src/include/os/rt_linux.h
patching file src/Makefile
patching file src/os/linux/config.mk
patching file src/os/linux/Makefile.6
patching file src/os/linux/Makefile.clean
patching file src/os/linux/pci_main_dev.c
patching file src/os/linux/rt_linux.c
patching file src/tools/Makefile




Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-45-generic -C src/ LINUX_SRC=/lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rt3290sta: 2.6.0.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-45-generic/x86_64 failed for rt3290sta(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic (6.8.0-44.44) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.8.0-44-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/dkms.conf)
applying patch rt3290sta.patch...patching file src/include/os/rt_linux.h
patching file src/Makefile
patching file src/os/linux/config.mk
patching file src/os/linux/Makefile.6
patching file src/os/linux/Makefile.clean
patching file src/os/linux/pci_main_dev.c
patching file src/os/linux/rt_linux.c
patching file src/tools/Makefile




Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=6.8.0-44-generic -C src/ LINUX_SRC=/lib/modules/6.8.0-44-generic/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rt3290sta: 2.6.0.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.8.0-44-generic/x86_64 failed for rt3290sta(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.8.0-44-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 11
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-44-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Got same issue with bluetooth-4.4/0.1 instead of rt3290sta.
Seems to be fixed by:
$ sudo dkms remove bluetooth-4.4/0.1 --all
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/src/bluetooth-4.4-0.1/
(nothing relevant found in /etc/modprobe.d).

Got same issue with evdi 5.1.26  sudo dkms remove evdi/5.1.26 --all  sudo rm -rf /usr/src/evdi-5.1.26/  sudo apt autoremove 

Ok, I kindda solved the issue by removing dkms.conf file from /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/source/.
I guess I should have removed the whole rt3290sta module, but I don't remember how to do it properly, it was installed with some custom package

I've seen that error. I had to remove DKMS package called akvcam. In your case, it seems to be rt3290sta. akvcam seemed to not be compatible with new kernel so it was breaking my upgrade.
In my case, I had to remove 2 versions of akvcam to allow the configuration of the new kernel. Link for removal instructions which allowed me to go forward and fix it all with sudo apt upgrade
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68261311
Quote from the link:

To remove the module, you need to run sudo dkms remove modul/version --all to prevent it from being rebuilt during the next update, you must also remove the sources under /usr/src/.


here is an example of how to remove akvcam module

dkms status


akvcam, 1.2.0, 5.12.14-arch1-1, x86_64: installed

sudo dkms remove akvcam/1.2.0 --all
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/akvcam-1.2.0/
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/akvcam.conf
good luck marco manngatter

